# Allow array of booleanNodes with random keys with Symfony Configurations and default values

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, config

I want to achieve the following configuration structure:

```
app:
    integrations:
        some: true
        random: true
        options: true
        user_can_make_these_up: true
```

Where I already added some defaults: `mykey: true` and `myotherkey: false`

So in this case the compiled configuration should be:

```
[
    mykey => true,
    myotherkey => false,
    some => true,
    random => true,
    options => true,
    user_can_make_these_up => true,
]
```

I tried the following:

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('integrations')
            ->ignoreExtraKeys()
            ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
            ->children()
                ->booleanNode('mykey')->defaultTrue()->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

But then I get an error "Unrecognized option "mykey" under "app". Available option is "integrations"."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you have defined the following configuration (somewhere in your project):

```
app:
   mykey: false
```

The error message `Unrecognized option "mykey" under "app"` can only arise with the above config. You are using the option `mykey` directly under `app`, which is not available. Only available (directly under `app`) is `integrations`

It should look like this:

```
app:
   integrations:
      mykey: false
```

Eg. the provided "configuration" (in your question and this thread) is not the same as your are using in your project.

**MIND**: Keep in mind that whenever you have multiple `.yaml` configurations with the same keys, you could be **overriding** the previous configuration. So the following example ***could*** lead to the same error, whenever the latter `.yaml` file is loaded last:

```
> /config/packages/services.yaml
app:
   integrations:
      mykey: false
```

```
> /config/packages/test.yaml
app:
   myKey: false
```